# How to cache dynamic fragments in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Let's say I set a "product" at my controller:

```
# products_controller.rb
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

And in my `/products/show.html.erb` I got:

```
<%= render :partial => 'products/description', :locals => { :product => @product } %>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<% cache do %>
  <%= render :partial => 'products/description', :locals => { :product => @product } %>
<% end %>
```

But, as you can see, the `description` partial takes a `product` local variable, generating, of course, a dynamic partial for every specific product.

My question is, how can I use Rail's cache so I only have to generate this partial content the first time an specific product is requested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is giving the cache a specific key, like "product_24_description". That way, each cache would be different:

```
cache "#{dom_id product}_description" do
  ...
end
```

While you're at it, watch this video (and related video) about [scaling Rails](http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/02/19/episode-8-memcached).